# How to create different submit actions in a loop using PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, loops

```
<table>
<?php   
    $ft = fopen("b.txt", "r");
    if (!$ft) {
        print "No accounts";
    } else {
        $data=file("b.txt");

        foreach ( $data as $line ) {
            $line=rtrim($line);
            list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k)=explode("\t",$line);

            echo "<tr><th>$a</th><th>$g</th><th>$b</th><th>$h</th>";
            echo '<form action="check1.php" method="post">
                  <th><input type="submit" value="Decline" name="Edit"></th>
                  </form></tr>';
        } /*END foreach*/

    } /*END if else*/ ?>
</table>
```

The `b.txt` contains:

```
 a     lbc     LA   0942455214     0942455214     2@email.com   23    412      09521266      w@emil.com    4444-02-13   
 ako   fedex   LA   092746421415   092746421415   A@email.com   ala   fornia   09865432478   a@email.com   2004-04-23
```

This will display a two-row table in a form of HTML, and in the end of the row  there is a `decline` button (see image below).

[image: This is the output]

The question is, where should I put this:

```
   if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {
       $delete = $a;
       echo $delete;
   }
```

so that if I click the first decline button, it will display "a", and if I click the second one it will display "ako"?

Comment: Use the `<button>` element, then put the value of `$a` to the value property of the `<button>`, that way you can pass the value to the POST

Comment: By the way, your `<form></form>` should be inside your `<th></th>`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<button>` instead of submit, then try something like this:

```
 echo '<button type="submit" value="' . $a .'" name="btnDecline">DECLINE</button>'

if(isset($_POST['btnDecline']))
{
   $delete = $_POST['btnDecline'];
   echo $delete;
}
```

Comment: there is no display.. I tried to input any value there and its working but $a doesn't echo anything.

Comment: <button type="submit" value="' . $a .'" name="btnDecline">DECLINE</button> 
I tried this code and its working now thank you